# Replacing each letter in a string with chars A-Z (Runtime problems)

Tags: c++, runtime

I'm currently programming a spell checker that generates suggestions if a word is spelled incorrectly. One of the algorithms that generates a suggestion replaces each letter in the word with every letter from A-Z (for example, if 'phkne' was being spellchecked, it would find the word 'phone'). This is the current function that I'm using to do this

```
//replace each letter in the word with all letters from the alphabet
void replaceLetters(string word, Hashtable & wordList)
{
  char letters[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
  string copy = word;
  for (int i = 0; i < word.length() + 1; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
          copy = word;
          replace(copy.begin(), copy.end(), copy[i], letters[j]);
          if (wordList.contains(copy))
            {
                  cout << copy << endl; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution works, but the runtime is extremely slow. I'm assuming the char of letters and the nested for loops slows things down, but I can't reason a faster solution.

This is my contains function from my Hash table implementation

```
bool Hashtable::contains(string item)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < table[i].size() + 1; j++)
        {
          if (table[i].get(j) == item)
            {
               return true;
            }
        }
    }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Use a different data structure, such as [a trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  As noted at the link, -- "Tries are also well suited for implementing approximate matching algorithms,[8] including those used in **spell checking** and hyphenation[4] software."

Comment: You should also think about multithreading to improve performance

Comment: What you implemented is not a hashtable.  It is a simple, naive, loop testing all elements until you find the correct one.

Comment: *This solution works, but the runtime is extremely slow* -- Nothing will significantly speed up your current code until 1) You use (or implement) a bonafide hashtable, or 2) You use a different data structure to do the lookup, such as a trie.  Nested `for` loops is a tell-tale sign you're not going to have a fast implementation.

Comment: A "contains" operation for a hash table had damn-well-better contain at least one actual hash operation of the input key. Yours does not. You're scanning every entry in your table until you find a match, *regardless* of whether the key hashed to a specific collision list. Short Version: You're `contains` is dreadful. Calculate the hash code mod table size of your `item`, and check only that collision list; the rest are, by definition of hashing, pointless to enumerate.

Comment: You could arrange your `letters` in order of frequency of positive substitution (26x26 matrix). You could trawl a lot of badly spelled words to build up a frequency table for that.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're completely right, stupid error on my part. I was wondering why it was so slow, when I forgot to hash the damn thing. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Nick remember to mark one of the answers as accepted if it satisfies you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed greatly depends on the implementation of your `Hashtable`, since its `contains()` method is called in the hottest path of the code.
The `contains()` method that you posted indicates that yours is not an hashtable at all, and since it performs an exhaustive search, it's very slow.

Do not reinvent the wheel (especially using a very slow one), be sure to use the fastest possible hashtable at your disposal (fastest for reading, not writing). Maybe `std:unordered_map` or a `std::unordered_set`, but do your research.

Maybe you could also try different algorithms, for example using some heuristic to avoid searching the whole space of possible solutions. One possibility could be calculating the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between your word and every word in the dictionary, keeping a list of those with a short distance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another container to hold `wordList`. Use `std::set` or `std:unordered_set` of strings.
`std::set` is slower than `std:unordered_set` but it requires less memory.
If you are able to use more memory, then you should use `std:unordered_set` - it is faster. Use find() method to find possible key.

Also important thing is to separate this task in several threads. To get 
 max count of threads to be executed you can use `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` method. It returns number of concurrent threads supported.
So for example you can separate algorithm on equal parts to calculate part of combination by each thread.
But there is no easy solution. Need to test and check which way is better. Some of these ideas can help you.